# How to run tomcat with -D system property for doc

Tags: tomcat, ant, tomcat6

In tomcat config we have a docBase like this:

```
<Context path="/" docBase="webapps/rootExample"/>
```

Is it possible to provide docBase property at runtime at tomcat startup from some external properties file or as a -D system property?

Answer (score 0):

System properties are global to the entire JVM, so the answer is no.

What you could do is to provide `<context-param>` in your `web.xml` which does a similar thing.

Another alternative would be to use JNDI where each webapp has some sort of mechanism of checking for configuration setting in there.